# Android DownloadManager how to mark file as temporary before finishing downloading

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have a `DownloadManager` to download video so that I can use player to play. But when I start to download, it has generated the unfinished `.mp4` file, so when I tried to play before finish downloading, it will show error, is that possible change its extension before finish downloading?

```
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);    
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);    
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setDescription("caching video").setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Android/data/", id + ".mp4");
long id = manager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem in a little different way
Instead of `change its extension before finish downloading` you need to start the download with the changed extension like this:

```
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setDescription("caching video").setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Android/data/", id + ".mp4.tmp");
```

and once download is finished, rename file to `"/Android/data/", id + ".mp4"`

Comment: so i need to add download finish listener?

Comment: @ywj7931, it you are going to implement my solution, then yes